# What for a Kinase Assay?

Tags: lab-techniques, western-blot, phosphorylation

I am wondering why to use a kinase assay, since we can extract the proteins from cells and then do a Western with the specific antibodies we want to use.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. However you need to provide much more background to your question before anyone can help you. What is the context of your question? What experiment are you doing? What are you trying to discover? Is this a teaching experiment or real research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very simple answer: scale. If a drug company wants to screen a million-compound library to find which ones inhibit the kinase activity of a certain target, they're not about to do a million IPs and a million Western blots. Instead, they'll use recombinant kinase and substrate peptides, with a variety of readout systems to choose from.

Other reasons include not having a good phospho-specific antibody to the substrate, very low expression of the kinase and/or substrate, complicated protocols necessary to activate the kinase *in vitro*, lack of a good model system, and more.